# How to fix this emacs warning: Warning (bytecomp): ‘mapcar’ called for effect; use ‘mapc’ or ‘dolist’ instead

Tags: windows, emacs, warnings

Installed the latest emacs on Windows 7, copied package folders from last installation, updated packages. Getting warning (see below). Googling the warning shows some brief discussion from 2007, but nothing dumbed down for non-lispers. Does anyone know what this warning refers to and what the fix is?

```
Warning (bytecomp): ‘mapcar’ called for effect; use ‘mapc’ or ‘dolist’ instead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19507/10761) from the Emacs stack exchange. If you read it, you will see that you have a couple of options for how to fix this problem:

1. Add the following comments to the bottom of the file(s) causing the warning:

   ```
   ;; Local Variables:
   ;; byte-compile-warnings: (not mapcar)
   ;; End:
   ```
2. Set the `byte-compile-warnings` variable via `M-x customize-variable RET byte-compile-warnings RET`. Click the `Value Menu` button and select `Some` by pressing `1`, then check the box labeled `mapcar`. Finally, click `Apply and Save`.

The warning should stop appearing after you do one of these two things.

Comment: Thnx. What variable stores the list of files in 1? In this case, 2 did not work, neither through customization:  '(byte-compile-warnings (quote (mapcar))), or adding (setq-default byte-compile-warnings '(not mapcar)) to the init. Emacs, definitely worth all the effort in the end (y)

Comment: @F.Certainly. There is no variable which stores the file(s) causing warnings as far as I know. You might just have to `grep` your packages folder or init file(s) for `mapcar` and just try adding those comments to the matching files. I'm really not sure why #2 doesn't work for you; you might try restarting Emacs and see whether the warnings still pop up. If so, you might want to check and make sure that `byte-compile-warnings` has the expected value after restarting Emacs. If it doesn't, try putting the variable assignment for `byte-compile-warnings` at the very end of your init sequence.

Comment: Thnks, it is odd, restart-emacs = no change to warning when byte-compile-warnings = (not mapcar) || (mapcar). So far greps have no 'mapcar' matches..so who knows, lol. Maybe recompiling the packages will work. Cheers.

Comment: Right, well what can you do. Grep wasn't using find properly (setq find-program "C:/cygwin64/bin/find.exe")

Comment: @F.Certainly. Yeah, sorry about that. It seems that Windows is always a funky environment, even when using something like Cygwin.